# Can I use the SEO Lite title field as a Structure custom title?

Tags: structure, title, seo-lite

In some cases I need to use custom page titles while using Structure. I know you can set up a custom field and use that, but I am also wondering if there is a way to use the Title field within the SEO Lite module?

If not, I think I could always hide the SEO Lite Title field and replace it with my own custom field, but I am hoping there is a simple way to accomplish it natively?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pop the following in your header:

```
{exp:seo_lite entry_id="{structure:page:entry_id}"}
```

If you **do not** add a title into the SEO Lite title field, the entry title will be used for the title meta tag.

If you **do** add a title into the SEO Lite title field, that will be used.

Comment: Works great! I <3 you...